# How can I assign a specific itemView to a certain model in a CompositeView collection?

Tags: marionette

I am using backbone.marionette and want to use different views for some Items from a collection passed to a CompositeView. Is this possible?

```
var vText = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template : "forms/form-element",
    className : "control-group"
});

var vCheckbox = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template : "forms/form-element-checkbox",
    className : "control-group"
});

var vForm = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    tagName : 'form',
    template : 'forms/form',
    className : 'crud-form form-horizontal',
    itemView : // use different view for specific items based on collection modelData
})
```

I tried:

```
itemView : function(model) {

        switch(model.get('inputType')) {
            case "checkbox":
                return vCheckbox;
            break;
            default:
                return vText;
            break;  
        }
    }
```

But doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

this isn't directly supported right now, but wouldn't be too hard to add for your project's needs

https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/backbone.marionette.collectionview.js#L105-115

this is the function that retrieves the value of the `itemView` setting for a view. You could override it in your specific view:

```
Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

  // ...

  getItemView: function(){
    return this.itemView();
  }

});
```

This seems like something that should be added to marionette directly, as well. Can you add an issue to the github issues list? https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/issues link back to this SO post from the ticket.

Comment: Hi Derick, I've added the issue. I am using the async Marionette and the solution to this problem is not as simple as you suggested.

I've managed to get to get different templates for certain models by changing code at a few places in the core files. Because of the async nature the initial order of the collection gets changed which it should not. 
Right now it doesn't matter much but I hope you'll get to implement it. 

I'll add another issue with some things I found out searching for a solution.

Keep up the good work!